# Modifying keys for an object that has arrays of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference

There is an object where each key is an array of objects.

For example, in the following example `data` is an object having keys where each key is an array of object(s):

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Successful",
    "data": {
        "manual": [
        {
            "vendor_id": 1,
            "price": 4590,
            "discounts": {
            "micro": 0,
            "macro": 120
            },
            "vendor": "Vendor 1",
            "customer_rating": "3.0/5",
            "sla_compliance": 90,
            "system_flag": "Green"
        }
        ],
        "nearest": [
        {
            "vendor_id": 1,
            "price": 4590,
            "discounts": {
            "micro": 0,
            "macro": 120
            },
            "vendor": "Vendor 1",
            "customer_rating": "3.0/5",
            "sla_compliance": 90,
            "system_flag": "Green"
        }
        ],
        "auto": [
        {
            "vendor_id": 1,
            "price": 4590,
            "discounts": {
            "micro": 0,
            "macro": 120
            },
            "vendor": "Vendor 1",
            "customer_rating": "3.0/5",
            "sla_compliance": 90,
            "system_flag": "Green"
        }
        ],
        "ticket_id": 72
    }
    }
```

I need to add/delete keys from the each object that is inside the array. For example, I need to add `name` key for each object inside the key `manual`. Likeways for other arrays of objects like `nearest`, `auto`. What would be the way to do this?

I tried to modify one key, and it changes the complete object. How could I avoid the reference thing here?

Comment: For plain objects, "keys" can't be objects, however values associated with keys (properties) can be objects (or any value type). Why not `obj.data.manual[0].name = 'whatever'` where *obj* is a reference to the outermost object? What have you tried?

Comment: @RobG What if I want to assign `obj.data.manual[0].name` to `obj.data.manual[0].myname` and then delete `obj.data.manual[0].name`. Won't it delete `obj.data.manual[0].myyname` too?

Comment: You can use typeof obj.data.manual[0].myyname, if it's a object, then yes.

Comment: No, it won't, only the property is deleted. If an object has been assigned to the property, then it will persist as long as there are other references to it.

Comment: You need to show what you tried, what the result was and what you wanted.

Comment: I don't get why you don't just assign things to it? That's all there is to `adding keys`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

Say your data structure is called `cars`:

```
var cars = {
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Successful",
    "data": {
        "manual": [
        {
             ...
```

Then you could add a property called `name` to the items under the property `manual` like

```
cars.data.manual = cars.data.manual.map(i => Object.assign({name: 'My ' + i.vendor}, i));
```

And similarly, to other items under different properties.

You can

```
console.log(cars);
```

afterwards to verify the result.